# Generate barcode code128 with fpdi don't get read when printed at 203 dpi

Tags: php, pdf, printing, fpdi, code128

I generate a barcode with fpdi and php:

```
use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
require ('fpdf181/fpdf.php');
require ('FPDI203/src/autoload.php');

$pdf = new Fpdi('L','mm',array(106.36,25.9));

$titulo1 = "Image Processor";
$titulo2 = "VPC";
$code='011892001462081';


//Dimensiones de codigos de barras
$largoCodigo = 17;
$altoCodigo =3;

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(0); //Disable print to the next page.

$pdf->Code128(36,7,$code,$largoCodigo,$altoCodigo);

$pdf->Output();
```

The barcode is generated well, but when it is printed the barcode is unreadable by the pistol. I'm using a Monarch 9416 XL printer. 203dpi

How can achieve that my barcode can be read by the pistol?
I have another barcode of the same size, but i have no idea how it was printed, and this can be read by the pistol.

Here are a data page, but i don't know how to apply the solution to my code: 
[Link with the solution that propose a web page](https://www.idautomation.com/kb/print-quality.html)

i used the Code128 library i added the Code128 function to FPDI:

[Link library](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script88.php)

//Barcode generator

```
protected $T128;                                         // Tableau des codes 128
protected $ABCset = "";                                  // jeu des caractères éligibles au C128
protected $Aset = "";                                    // Set A du jeu des caractères éligibles
protected $Bset = "";                                    // Set B du jeu des caractères éligibles
protected $Cset = "";                                    // Set C du jeu des caractères éligibles
protected $SetFrom;                                      // Convertisseur source des jeux vers le tableau
protected $SetTo;                                        // Convertisseur destination des jeux vers le tableau
protected $JStart = array("A"=>103, "B"=>104, "C"=>105); // Caractères de sélection de jeu au début du C128
protected $JSwap = array("A"=>101, "B"=>100, "C"=>99);   // Caractères de changement de jeu

//____________________________ Extension du constructeur _______________________
function __construct($orientation='P', $unit='mm', $format='A4') {

    parent::__construct($orientation,$unit,$format);

    $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2);           //0 : [ ]               // composition des caractères
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2);           //1 : [!]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1);           //2 : ["]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3);           //3 : [#]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2);           //4 : [$]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2);           //5 : [%]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3);           //6 : [&]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2);           //7 : [']
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2);           //8 : [(]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3);           //9 : [)]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2);           //10 : [*]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2);           //11 : [+]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2);           //12 : [,]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2);           //13 : [-]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1);           //14 : [.]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2);           //15 : [/]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2);           //16 : [0]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1);           //17 : [1]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1);           //18 : [2]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2);           //19 : [3]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1);           //20 : [4]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2);           //21 : [5]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2);           //22 : [6]
    $this->T128[] = array(3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1);           //23 : [7]
    $this->T128[] = array(3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2);           //24 : [8]
    $this->T128[] = array(3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2);           //25 : [9]
    $this->T128[] = array(3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1);           //26 : [:]
    $this->T128[] = array(3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2);           //27 : [;]
    $this->T128[] = array(3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2);           //28 : [<]
    $this->T128[] = array(3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1);           //29 : [=]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3);           //30 : [>]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1);           //31 : [?]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1);           //32 : [@]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3);           //33 : [A]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3);           //34 : [B]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1);           //35 : [C]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3);           //36 : [D]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3);           //37 : [E]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1);           //38 : [F]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3);           //39 : [G]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3);           //40 : [H]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1);           //41 : [I]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3);           //42 : [J]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1);           //43 : [K]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1);           //44 : [L]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3);           //45 : [M]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1);           //46 : [N]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1);           //47 : [O]
    $this->T128[] = array(3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1);           //48 : [P]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1);           //49 : [Q]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1);           //50 : [R]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3);           //51 : [S]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1);           //52 : [T]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1);           //53 : [U]
    $this->T128[] = array(3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3);           //54 : [V]
    $this->T128[] = array(3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1);           //55 : [W]
    $this->T128[] = array(3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1);           //56 : [X]
    $this->T128[] = array(3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3);           //57 : [Y]
    $this->T128[] = array(3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1);           //58 : [Z]
    $this->T128[] = array(3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1);           //59 : [[]
    $this->T128[] = array(3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1);           //60 : [\]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1);           //61 : []]
    $this->T128[] = array(4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1);           //62 : [^]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4);           //63 : [_]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2);           //64 : [`]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4);           //65 : [a]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1);           //66 : [b]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2);           //67 : [c]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1);           //68 : [d]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4);           //69 : [e]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2);           //70 : [f]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4);           //71 : [g]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1);           //72 : [h]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2);           //73 : [i]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1);           //74 : [j]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1);           //75 : [k]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4);           //76 : [l]
    $this->T128[] = array(4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1);           //77 : [m]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2);           //78 : [n]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1);           //79 : [o]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2);           //80 : [p]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2);           //81 : [q]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1);           //82 : [r]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2);           //83 : [s]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2);           //84 : [t]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1);           //85 : [u]
    $this->T128[] = array(4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2);           //86 : [v]
    $this->T128[] = array(4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2);           //87 : [w]
    $this->T128[] = array(4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1);           //88 : [x]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1);           //89 : [y]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1);           //90 : [z]
    $this->T128[] = array(4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1);           //91 : [{]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3);           //92 : [|]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1);           //93 : [}]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1);           //94 : [~]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3);           //95 : [DEL]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1);           //96 : [FNC3]
    $this->T128[] = array(4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3);           //97 : [FNC2]
    $this->T128[] = array(4, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1);           //98 : [SHIFT]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1);           //99 : [Cswap]
    $this->T128[] = array(1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1);           //100 : [Bswap]                
    $this->T128[] = array(3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1);           //101 : [Aswap]
    $this->T128[] = array(4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1);           //102 : [FNC1]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2);           //103 : [Astart]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4);           //104 : [Bstart]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2);           //105 : [Cstart]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1);           //106 : [STOP]
    $this->T128[] = array(2, 1);                       //107 : [END BAR]

    for ($i = 32; $i <= 95; $i++) {                                            // jeux de caractères
        $this->ABCset .= chr($i);
    }
    $this->Aset = $this->ABCset;
    $this->Bset = $this->ABCset;

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; $i++) {
        $this->ABCset .= chr($i);
        $this->Aset .= chr($i);
    }
    for ($i = 96; $i <= 127; $i++) {
        $this->ABCset .= chr($i);
        $this->Bset .= chr($i);
    }
    for ($i = 200; $i <= 210; $i++) {                                           // controle 128
        $this->ABCset .= chr($i);
        $this->Aset .= chr($i);
        $this->Bset .= chr($i);
    }
    $this->Cset="0123456789".chr(206);

    for ($i=0; $i<96; $i++) {                                                   // convertisseurs des jeux A & B
        @$this->SetFrom["A"] .= chr($i);
        @$this->SetFrom["B"] .= chr($i + 32);
        @$this->SetTo["A"] .= chr(($i < 32) ? $i+64 : $i-32);
        @$this->SetTo["B"] .= chr($i);
    }
    for ($i=96; $i<107; $i++) {                                                 // contrôle des jeux A & B
        @$this->SetFrom["A"] .= chr($i + 104);
        @$this->SetFrom["B"] .= chr($i + 104);
        @$this->SetTo["A"] .= chr($i);
        @$this->SetTo["B"] .= chr($i);
    }
}

//________________ Fonction encodage et dessin du code 128 _____________________
function Code128($x, $y, $code, $w, $h) {
    $Aguid = "";                                                                      // Création des guides de choix ABC
    $Bguid = "";
    $Cguid = "";
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($code); $i++) {
        $needle = substr($code,$i,1);
        $Aguid .= ((strpos($this->Aset,$needle)===false) ? "N" : "O"); 
        $Bguid .= ((strpos($this->Bset,$needle)===false) ? "N" : "O"); 
        $Cguid .= ((strpos($this->Cset,$needle)===false) ? "N" : "O");
    }

    $SminiC = "OOOO";
    $IminiC = 4;

    $crypt = "";
    while ($code > "") {
                                                                                    // BOUCLE PRINCIPALE DE CODAGE
        $i = strpos($Cguid,$SminiC);                                                // forçage du jeu C, si possible
        if ($i!==false) {
            $Aguid [$i] = "N";
            $Bguid [$i] = "N";
        }

        if (substr($Cguid,0,$IminiC) == $SminiC) {                                  // jeu C
            $crypt .= chr(($crypt > "") ? $this->JSwap["C"] : $this->JStart["C"]);  // début Cstart, sinon Cswap
            $made = strpos($Cguid,"N");                                             // étendu du set C
            if ($made === false) {
                $made = strlen($Cguid);
            }
            if (fmod($made,2)==1) {
                $made--;                                                            // seulement un nombre pair
            }
            for ($i=0; $i < $made; $i += 2) {
                $crypt .= chr(strval(substr($code,$i,2)));                          // conversion 2 par 2
            }
            $jeu = "C";
        } else {
            $madeA = strpos($Aguid,"N");                                            // étendu du set A
            if ($madeA === false) {
                $madeA = strlen($Aguid);
            }
            $madeB = strpos($Bguid,"N");                                            // étendu du set B
            if ($madeB === false) {
                $madeB = strlen($Bguid);
            }
            $made = (($madeA < $madeB) ? $madeB : $madeA );                         // étendu traitée
            $jeu = (($madeA < $madeB) ? "B" : "A" );                                // Jeu en cours

            $crypt .= chr(($crypt > "") ? $this->JSwap[$jeu] : $this->JStart[$jeu]); // début start, sinon swap

            $crypt .= strtr(substr($code, 0,$made), $this->SetFrom[$jeu], $this->SetTo[$jeu]); // conversion selon jeu

        }
        $code = substr($code,$made);                                           // raccourcir légende et guides de la zone traitée
        $Aguid = substr($Aguid,$made);
        $Bguid = substr($Bguid,$made);
        $Cguid = substr($Cguid,$made);
    }                                                                          // FIN BOUCLE PRINCIPALE

    $check = ord($crypt[0]);                                                   // calcul de la somme de contrôle
    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($crypt); $i++) {
        $check += (ord($crypt[$i]) * $i);
    }
    $check %= 103;

    $crypt .= chr($check) . chr(106) . chr(107);                               // Chaine cryptée complète

    $i = (strlen($crypt) * 11) - 8;                                            // calcul de la largeur du module
    $modul = $w/$i;

    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($crypt); $i++) {                                      // BOUCLE D'IMPRESSION
        $c = $this->T128[ord($crypt[$i])];
        for ($j=0; $j<count($c); $j++) {
            $this->Rect($x,$y,$c[$j]*$modul,$h,"F");
            $x += ($c[$j++]+$c[$j])*$modul;
        }
    }
}



}
```

Comment: Just for sanity have you tried reading the barcode with your phone?

Comment: Yes, but the phone don't read the code.  The phone only read on the screen but only when i make zoom to the pdf page.

Comment: Not familiar with FPDI. Actually thought you were misspelling FPDF at first. Looking at their repo I see no Code128 function. Can you share the code?

Comment: i believe if i make the width of every rectangle smaller i can create a barcode readable by the scanner pistol. How can achieve that?

Comment: First stab would be with the `$w` on the `Code128()` function. Then could look at this line: `$i = (strlen($crypt) * 11) - 8;` and line just below it. Scrunches... `$m = $w/$i;` where m is the width for the bars that make up a character. (total width (w) divided by length of total characters (i).

Comment: @ficuscr i used: $m = $m *0.01 and the codebar almost disappear.

Comment: @ficuscr i used: $m = $m *0.01 and the codebar almost disappear. $m = $m /0.01 and the codebar its huge.  $m = $m +0.01 and the codebar its a little better(bars is a little small) $m= $m - 0.01 and the codebar its a little worst(bars is a little big).  i don't know what i do. i need my codebar of lenght = 17mm and the height= any

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177682/discussion-between-ficuscr-and-mrlinux).

Comment: Only when i used the full width its when worked(the pistol detect). But i don't want that. It's possible, to make it  to that size, i have a label with this codebar length from another device and worked.